How to control two pumps with one switch?
I am not an engineer, and I need help.
I have two pumps (A and B) that I want to control them simultaneously (A and B) or individually (A or B). I want to use a single switch with three options:

Switch position 1: turn Pumps A and B simultaneously on.
Switch position 3: Turn only Pump A on.
Switch position 3: Turn only Pump B on.

This is the pump I use: https://es.rs-online.com/web/p/bombas-de-desplazamiento-positivo/7026894?gb=a
I would like to purchase that switch from RS online. I'd appreciate it if you could help me determine what type of switch or which one I should buy.

Welcome! Is the second switch position supposed to be 2 instead of 3?

thanks a lot for your prompt and great responses. I found this on RS -Online:https://es.rs-online.com/web/p/interruptores-de-levas/1834363?gb=s I will order this, and apply winny´s suggested circuit. Thanks Simon, for your simple and useful suggestions. Best

That’s not a three position switch but a two + turn off. Won’t give you three options unless you abuse the 0 one with external relay(s).

@gunes - Hi (a) I converted your "answer" into the comment above. An answer shouldn't be used to say thank you. Confirming another answer isn't a valid use for an answer either. I know the answer box (labeled "Your Answer" at the bottom of the page) looks like most forums and it might seem the obvious way to add something - but that is only for answers to the original question, not for comments. (b) From your (now) comment, it seems you have received suitable answers. If so, please review the actions in this article about how to mark the topic as solved. TY

Hi Winny, I apologise for my knowledge in this topic. It says 4 position, which I thought it is fine. It would be great  if you can suggest me a three position switch. 1. https://www.amazon.com/Taiss-Position-Universal-Latching-terminals/dp/B09P9T86TT/ref=pd_pss_dp_d_1_d_sccl_3_1/137-5776087-2058367?pd_rd_w=wnY1O&content-id=amzn1.sym.427cdbb1-779c-4be6-8c9b-81ddadc2ade4&pf_rd_p=427cdbb1-779c-4be6-8c9b-81ddadc2ade4&pf_rd_r=VRJAFWWSWBQ0P7MTAXFA&pd_rd_wg=SzQud&pd_rd_r=4a9ddf62-3325-4a0e-823d-cd14d7ae1c62&pd_rd_i=B09P9T86TT&psc=1

It’s a 4PDT switch plus off, probably intended for 3 phase motors and two speeds.

If you can find a double-pole, three-position (3-throw) switch, you would wire everything as follows:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The switch is really two electrically independent switches, but mechanically linked to the same physical knob or lever. Search for "DP3T", or "2P3T". You might find suppliers describing their switches using terms like "double-pole" and "triple-throw".
With the switches in the left position (as shown), only pump A circuit is closed. The right-most position would have only pump B circuit closed. The centre position would apply power to both.
Using a four-throw switch, one of the four positions could be used to switch both pumps off.

Where did you find that SP3T symbol?

@winny I just drew it with arrows and "degree" symbols in text. No secret CircuitLab tricks to reveal, I'm afraid!

Oh, that would explain it.

Several ways to do it. If you can't find a DP3T switch as per Simon's suggestion, here is another way. There aren't any symbol available for SP3T switch, so you have to imagine the circle for the third output. Sorry about that. The relay is a DPDT or DPST type.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
